# How to use the iabr register on the powerpc (e300 core)

Tags: debugging, assembly, breakpoints, powerpc

I would like to know how to use the iabr register to set a breakpoint. The manual says something about a isync instruction but this doesn't seem to be working. Can someone help please?

The code I'm using:

```
asm ("isync");
asm volatile ("mtspr 1010,%0;" : : "r"(val));
asm ("isync");
asm ("isync");
```

Answer (score 0):

[MPC604](http://www.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/data_sheet/MPC604.pdf) gives a hint:

> An instruction address breakpoint exception occurs when the address (bits 0 to 29) in the IABR matches the next instruction to complete in the completion unit, and the IABR enable bit (bit 30) is set to 1.

If the address of the instruction you want to break on is `addr`, you need to do `val = addr | 2`. I don't know what bit 31 does.